# Debian Buster: "tcpdump -w file" works only in some directories

Tags: tcpdump, apparmor, debian-buster

The following command (called as user root with and without `-i eno`)

```
tcpdump -w a.dump -i eno1 portrange 27900-27901
```

works only in some directories, eg. `/tmp` and `/root`. But it works not in other directories, for example not in `/temp` created with:

```
mkdir /temp
chown root.root /temp
chmod 700 /temp
```

Stopped `apparmor`, but it doesn't help.

Any ideas to enable other directories?

Comment: This is more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as it does not involve a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was AppArmor. I learned the stopping the service does not stop the protection. In detail, there were some rules that don't allow the file extension `.dump` in *unknown* directories. The file extension `.pcap` is allowed in all places. Now I have disabled the control of `tcpdump`.

I see no reason to forbid `*.dump`, but to allow `*.pcap`. Who thinks up such rules?