# shell_exec() tcpdump from php

Tags: php, bash, tcpdump

I am trying to write a  script in php to run the following bash script using apache2+php7

```
#!/bin/bash
#cd  /home/cwc/http/www/html/admin/web/
nowfile=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
nohup tcpdump -w $nowfile.pcap -i enp2s0  >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Now I understand I might have to use full paths
The above code works with a non sudo user using bash because I added a user the the pcap group.
I'm trying to figure out why this will not work with php

```
<?php
$command = "/pathtoscript/tcpdmp.sh
shell_exec($command); //not working?
?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  the script is not getting invoked?

Comment: There are no error logs in /var/log/httpd/  .  Running on redhat AWS free tier.

Comment: `$command = "/pathtoscript/tcpdmp.sh"` you have not closed quotes

Comment: this happens because the the command  "nohup tcpdump -w $nowfile.pcap -i enp2s0" is throwing error.  and you are redirecting the output and error to /dev/null so it wont give anything back to PHP. try removing "  >> /dev/null 2>&1 & " and echo the shell_exec output. You will be able to see the error

Comment: It's probably a permission error as apache runs as a seperate user. So add the apache user to the pcap group. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: If running debian, then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900788/debian-buster-tcpdump-w-file-works-only-in-some-directories